# How do I set DeleteOnTermination to true in CloudFormation script for AWS Windows Instances?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation script which loads an ASG of Windows instances. Currently it does not contain any BlockDeviceMapping definition, and by default the Ebs volumes remain alive and unattached after the instances go down.

I've been trying to add an AWS::EC2:Instance clause with BlockDeviceMappings definitions, but all the examples I was able to find were for Linux instances, and they don't seem to be working, The following clause:

```
"OcrServiceStorageRelease" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties" : {
  "ImageId" : "ami-83b14fec",
      "BlockDeviceMappings" : [
            {   
            "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda1",
            "Ebs" : {
                    "DeleteOnTermination" : "true",
                    "VolumeSize" : "30",
                    "VolumeType" : "gp2"
               }
            }
        ]
      } 
  },
```

Results in the error message: 
    "The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations."

However, I didn't find anything in the AWS configuration. How do I configure this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making use of the [DeletionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) attribute in your template? DeleteOnTermination is true by default for an Ebs volume.

Remember you also have the option of adding a Volume as a resource and define its attachment (`AWS::EC2::Volume` and `AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment`), if that would help with the main issue.